How to apply custom button and function code in FB60?
We are implementing a custom function to attach DMS document for FI tcodes F-22, F-29, F-47, FB60, etc.
Currently, we added a custom button to FB60 and assigned function code to it and we created an implicit enhancement at the end on the form pai_user_command_1100 in MF05AIENJ include program. And before reaching the enhancement part, there is a check that throws an error saying Select a valid function in subroutine form fusszeile_verarbeiten in MF05AFF0_FUSSZEILE_VERARBEITEN include.
Please clarify any configurations I have missed or any flaw.

If creating "at the end" is too late, then create "at the beginning".

Yes, was thinking the same, might go for that.

Will there be an impact, if I return from the subroutine form after executing my custom function?

Have you looked into using the Generic Object Services to attach the DMS document after the FI-Document has been posted?
https://help.sap.com/docs/ABAP_PLATFORM_NEW/ea9793caa0964c93841c17a512524ef6/4d078bd464e05dc6e10000000a42189c.html?locale=de-DE
